# If $\mu$ is a measure, is $t\mapsto\mu([0,t])$ right-continuous with left-limits?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$ with $$f(t):=\mu([0,t])<\infty\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0.\tag1$$

> Is $f$ right- and/or left-continuous? Or does it at least have right- and/or left-limits?

We clearly want to use that a measure is continuous from below and from above: If $(A_n)$ is

1. an increasing sequence of measurable sets and $A=\bigcup_nA_n$; or
2. a decreasing sequence of measurable sets with $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ and $A=\bigcap_nA_n$,

then $\mu(A_n)\to\mu(A)$.

In order to show that $f$ is right-continuous, we would need to show that if $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ is decreasing and $t\ge0$ with $t_n\rightarrow{n\to\infty}t$, then $f(t_n)\to f(t)$. Now, if I'm not missing something, we should have $\bigcap_n[0,t_n]=[0,t]$ and hence this should hold.

I don't think that $f$ is left-continuous, but the left limits should at least exist. Maybe we can show that if $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ is increasing and $t\ge0$ with $t_n\to t$, then $\bigcup_{[0,t_n)}=[0,t]$?

Comment: Try showing that $f$ is non-decreasing, then you'd get left and right limits existing for "free" (every non-decreasing function has left and right limits at every point). Now you just have to show which of those limits equals to the function's value at a point, and if you can't perhaps you should try coming up with an example where it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t_n\nearrow t$ as $n\to\infty$, then $f(t_n)$ is a non-decreasing sequence bounded from above (by $\mu([0,t])$). [Thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), $f(t_n)$ has a limit. In particular, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)=\sup_{n\ge 1}f(t_n)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, the "only thing" we can show is that $f$ is right-continuous and has left-limits, right? But it is not left-continuous in general.

Comment: @0xbadf00d That's right. $\mu$ may have atoms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There's one question left: The problem is that $\bigcap_n[0,t_n]=[0,t]$ (in the decreasing case), but $\bigcup_n[0,t_n]\ne[0,t]$ (in the increasing case), right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d That's right. In the second case $t$ does not belong to any $[0,t_n]$.

Comment: What I'm wondering: If $\mu$ is a counting measure (i.e. purely atomic and diffuse which implies that $\mu(B)=\left|D\cap B\right|$, where $D:=\{t\ge0:t\text{ is an atom of }\mu\}$), what can we say about $\Delta f(t):=f(t)-\lim_{s\to t-}f(s)$? Can we show that it belongs to $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d If $\mu$ is a counting measure, there are at most finite number of jumps before $t$. So $\Delta f(t)$ is indeed either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: How do we prove that? Does it follow from the formula $\mu(B)=|D\cap B|$? I already know that a càdlàg function has only finitely many jumps of a fixed size on a bounded interval (i.e. $\{[0,t]:|\Delta f(s)|\ge c\}$ is finite for all $c>0$).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. For simplicity, assume that $x:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb Z$ is any càdlàg function and $t>0$. Then, given $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$\forall s\in(t-\delta,t):|x(s)-x(t-)|<\varepsilon.$$ Since $x$ is $\mathbb Z$-valued and $\varepsilon<1$, this implies that $$\forall s\in(t-\delta,t):x(s)=x(t-).$$

Comment: However, the only thing I'm able to deduce from this is $$\forall s\in(t-\delta,t):|\Delta x(t)|=|x(t)-x(t-)|\le|x(t)-x(s)|.$$ But I don't see why we should be able to conclude $|x(t)-x(s)|\le1$ for all $s\in(t-\delta,t)$ (from which we obtain $\Delta x(s)\in\{0,1\}$ if $x$ is nondecreasing).

Comment: Wait. What is $\mu$ exactly? Are jumps "$> 1$" allowed?

Comment: In the question, $\mu$ is an arbitrary measure on $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$. But here in the comments I've asked you to assume that $\mu$ is a "counting measure", i.e. "purely atomic" - meaning that $D:=\{t\ge0:t\text{ is an atom of }\mu\}$ is countable and $\mu([0,\infty)\setminus D)=0$ - and $$\forall t\in D:\mu(\{t\})=1.$$ As I wrote before, this implies $\mu(B)=|B\cap D|$ for all $B\in\mathcal B([0,\infty))$.

Comment: OK. So jumps happen at $t_1,t_2,\ldots$ and at each jump $\mu([0,t_i])-\mu([0,t_i))=1$.

Comment: (Ignore the following side note if it's not relevant, but let me note that in the actual application that I've got in mind, $f(t)=\kappa(\omega,[0,t])$ for some fixed $\omega$, where $\kappa$ is a random Poisson measure. Maybe that's crucial, since this implies that $f$ is a Poisson process for which we know that the desired claim holds true.)

Comment: Well, yes, I see. $\mu([0,t_i])-\mu([0,t_i))=\mu(\{t_i\})=1$. So, the claim is rather trivial or is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Nope, I don't think you're missing anything.

Comment: Just one addendum: Isn't the left-limit at $t$ actually given by $\mu([0,t))$? If $t\ge0$ and $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)\setminus\{t\}$ is nondecreasing with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t$, then we should have $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}[0,t_n]=[0,t)$ and hence $\mu([0,t_n])\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu([0,t))$, right?

Comment: Still be interested in a response. Do you agree?

Comment: @0xbadf00d That's correct.